# Pure html based indoor navigation

Tags: gps, mobile, indoor, html5, trilateration

I would like to locate (position) people inside buildings without forcing them to download a native app. I'm focusing on iOS and Android devices.
I therefore thought about wifi triangulation (trilateration), GPS repeater, GSM beamforming or even [acoustic background spectrum](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2000011).

Is there any product/tool to achieve this task?

Comment: @mapperz: I don't think it's about *general* computing; i think it is about *spatial* computing. Is your issue that it is about *indoor* problems (rather than outdoor)? I agree that maybe it *could* be more detailed/descriptive in defining the situation/problem, but i do think it is on topic.

Comment: @martinf thank you martin, btw I posted here instead of stack overflow because I thought it was not suitable for SO, I therefore reposted it [here](http://superuser.com/questions/749819/pure-html-based-indoor-localisation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about it beyond what's written in this [press release](http://gisiindoors.com/news/gisi-indoors-announces-geometri-indoor-analytics-product-release) and briefly described in this [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GlZZI7RWKA0), but [GeoMetri](https://geometri.gisinc.com/) is a commercial HTML5 solution to indoor location tracking and analytics.

From the application's [help page](https://geometri.gisinc.com/help.html#about):

> ## About This Application
>
> This web-application is a cross-platform responsive HTML viewer designed to help physical locations (i.e. brick & mortar retailers, warehousing, medical facilities, entertainment venues, etc.) create insight through physical analytics.
>
> ...
>
> ### How does it work?
>
> The core of the technology relies on [WiFi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi). As physical consumers move
>   around, the wifi enabled devices we all carry (i.e. smartphones,
>   tablets, laptops, or even stand-alone wifi tags) send out probe
>   requests every few seconds (or minutes) to see what networks (if any)
>   are available. A digital [marco-polo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marco_Polo_%28game%29), if you will.
>
> As part of the request, the wifi access points receive the signal
>   strength between itself and the mobile device. This signal can be used
>   to create an *estimated* location which users of this application can
>   use to answer questions, such as:
>
> - How many vistors came to my location today?
> - Did my latest ad campaign make a difference?
> - How can I optimize my own staff to serve visitor traffic?

Comment: It seems to be the most realistic solution for now. Let's now check how accurate it is compared to iBeacon